# How to tackle with mosquitoes in my room?

Tags: cleaning, home

I am fed up of mosquitoes in my room .I have attached bathroom in my room and one window opening for cooler. I Have sprayed HIT but  after 1or 2 days again found them. I Have even used ALL OUT but nothing gave permanent solution. I have even suffered from dengue and malaria in the past , so don't want to have them again. Please Help me out with some effective idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no permanent solution to keeping mosquitoes out of a house, other than effective window screens. Many people are trying to find ways to prevent mosquitoes from breeding or to prevent them from carrying diseases such as malaria, dengue and zika.

You might best work on two areas:

1. Eliminate breeding places nearby, such as empty tires, open plastic pots and uncovered rain barrels. Mosquitoes do not fly long distances, so you can make a difference by working in your neighborhood.
2. Put up window screens and bed nets. [Insecticide Treated Nets (ITNs) "are highly effective in reducing childhood mortality and morbidity from malaria."](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15106149)

Answer (score 1):

A great advice of DrMoishe Pippik I must say.
But if you want to handle mosquitoes inside your house you can try using one of those electric Zappers for mosquitoes. You can [check out here](https://topmosquitokiller.com/best-mosquito-zappers-) to find more info on how to fight with mosquitoes and info about Zappers.